# FIND "show cpu usage" Option on nexus 5x with android 7.1.2

Tags: android

The option seems removed in Android 7.1.2. 
I need it to improve my OS performance.
I have tried and found it on Android 6

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its been removed. You will have to find an alternative on the play store.